# Android X Custom Notification View not displaying

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am trying to make a a custom view of notification but its not working

Below is code :

```
RemoteViews contentView=new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.my_notification_layout);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder=  new NotificationCompat.Builder(SplashScreenActivity.this, "DEFAULT_CHANNEL_MYAPP")
                .setCustomContentView(contentView)
                .setCustomBigContentView(contentView);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon_white);
            mBuilder.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.theme_color));
        } else {
            mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon_white);
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence name = getResources().getString(R.string.feroz_channel_name);
            String description = getResources().getString(R.string.feroz_channel_description);
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("DEFAULT_CHANNEL_MYAPP", name, importance);
            channel.enableLights(true);
            channel.setLightColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.theme_color));
            channel.enableVibration(true);
            channel.setDescription(description);

            NotificationManager notificationManager1 = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager1.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
        NotificationManager notificationManager1 = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager1.notify(11132,mBuilder.build());
```

Below is custom notification layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:text="My APP"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="@color/greyishBrown"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView9"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView9"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView9" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I am trying this in Android 10 version. The notification is not showing up

Comment: try add this line to your mBulider ->   .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())

Comment: I have tried your code and on emulator Android 10 it works. Did you mean notification doesn't showed at all? Or maybe you mean heads-up feature?